# Get the filtered data of an UiGrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I know that we get the filtered rows for an uigrid like :

var filteredData = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);

but how can i loop into it, i need to get an array like  what we get using 
$scope.gridoptions.data.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use forEach for that:

```
filteredData.forEach(function(row) { ... do something here; ... }
```

This would loop through the visible rows, giving you the possibility to do something with each row individually.

Comment: Note that the 'row' object is in fact a representation of the row itself. To access the data that is displayed within, you would have to use row.entity...
`$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid).forEach(function(row) { console.log(row.entity); })`